# Publish Maven project to Github Package

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, github, repository

**Objective**

Publish private maven project to GitHub packages as a private repo for use in other projects.

**Getting Error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project SecuritySpringBootContracts: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.sagar:SecuritySpringBootContracts:jar:0.0.3 from/to contracts (https://maven.pkg.github.com/sagarnayak/SecuritySpringBootContracts): transfer failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/sagarnayak/SecuritySpringBootContracts/com/sagar/SecuritySpringBootContracts/0.0.3/SecuritySpringBootContracts-0.0.3.jar, status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

**My private repository in GitHub**

https://github.com/sagarnayak/SecuritySpringBootContracts

**My code**

Settings.xml in **C:\Users\SAGAR\ .m2**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>github</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>contracts</id>
                <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/sagarnayak/SecuritySpringBootContracts</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<servers>
    <server>
        <id>contracts</id>
        <username>sagarnayak</username>
        <password>ghp_WRGrhj380s8vikAcZMp4j1z02</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sagar</groupId>
    <artifactId>SecuritySpringBootContracts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
    <name>SecuritySpringBootContracts</name>
    <description>SecuritySpringBootContracts</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.5.31</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>contracts</id>
            <name>contracts package</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/sagarnayak/SecuritySpringBootContracts</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

When I type ***mvnw deploy*** I get the error -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project SecuritySpringBootContracts: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.sagar:SecuritySpringBootContracts:jar:0.0.3 from/to contracts (https://maven.pkg.github.com/sagarnayak/SecuritySpringBootContracts): transfer failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/sagarnayak/SecuritySpringBootContracts/com/sagar/SecuritySpringBootContracts/0.0.3/SecuritySpringBootContracts-0.0.3.jar, status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

*Any suggestion is appreciated.*

Comment: it's really not recommended to post your passwords in your questions (or anywhere)

Comment: @MorBlau really appreciate the suggestion. The password is not correct it's truncated so I think it's safe with a wrong password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in this issue [Publishing GitHub Packages returns 422 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322121/publishing-github-packages-returns-422-error)
the cause appears to be the name of your maven artifact, it must be lowercase.

In your `pom.xml`, use for example `<artifactId>security-springboot-contracts</artifactId>` instead of `<artifactId>SecuritySpringBootContracts</artifactId>`

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot version which got created during startup of an application is wrong, it should be similar to like 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Ex: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT or  0.0.3-SNAPSHOT

in your case it got created with 0.0.3